# Can't apply prefab changes

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a problem when try to apply changes.
I have a GameObject in the hierarchy, i put other GO in a custom script and push apply button. All has saved, but 2 game object can't apply canges.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add new objects to the transform hierarchy, those new objects can't reference the prefab because they don't *know* they're part of the prefab. You can tell this because in the screen hierarchy list the prefab items are blue and the rest are not. You have to save the changes from an object that is part of the prefab first or redefine the prefab by dragging the parent object onto the prefab on the project list. Because a direct save was possible, it will overwrite.

The same is still essentially true for removing objects from the prefab hierarchy, except Unity knows that this is a breaking change (because it wouldn't be mappable *to* the prefab anymore) and informs you that doing so well remove ALL of the objects from the prefab upward reference and you can only save the changes by redefining the prefab by dragging it from scene to project (and possibly receive another warning about the objects being different: are you sure you want to overwrite?).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Solved!

Answer (score 2):

Likely those `Text` and `Transform` objects are found outside of the prefab. Prefabs can't reference external objects, since there's no guarantee they'll be available for every instantiation of the prefab.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Solved!

Comment: That explains it. This was bugging me a lot and now its solved. Thank you!.